# Axios 403 response springboot

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, axios, cors

I have a backend api and when i try to access it from a frontend client i get 403.

I set the base URL

```
const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8080'
});
```

Then i make login with an user and password and store the accessToken. The axius.post works fine

```
export default function Login() {

    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

    const history = useHistory();

    async function login(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        const data = {
            username,
            password,
        };

        try {
            const response = await api.post('auth/signin', data);

            console.log(response.data.accessToken)

            localStorage.setItem('username', username);
            localStorage.setItem('accessToken', response.data.accessToken);

            history.push('/books')
        } catch (err) {
            alert('Login failed! Try again!');
        }
    };
```

When i try to authenticate using the accesToken and make the axius.get i receive error 403

```
export default function Books(){

    const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);
    const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
    
    const username = localStorage.getItem('username');
    const access_token = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');


    const history = useHistory();

    useEffect(() => {

        api.get('api/book/v1', {
            Headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`
            },
            params: {
                page: 0,
                size: 10,
                direction: 'asc'
            }
        }).then(response => {
            setBooks(response.data._embedded.bookVOList)
        })

    })
```

The client runs on localhost:3000 and the server on localhost:8000

Here's the SecurityConfig class

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS) 
                .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/auth/signin", "/auth/refresh", "/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui.html**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                    .antMatchers("/users").denyAll()
                .and()
                    .cors()
                .and()
                .apply(new JwtConfigurer(tokenProvider));
    }}
```

And here's the WebConfig class

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    
        @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000", "http://localhost", "http://localhost:8080")
            .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS", "HEAD", "TRACE", "CONNECT")
            .allowCredentials(true);
    }
```

I've already tried to use proxy and adding @CrossOrigin to the controller class
I've used .allowedMethods("*") on addCorsMapping too but also didn't work

Comment: Your CORS middleware appears too late in the chain; it should be closer to the top, before `sessionManagement()` etc.

Comment: `http.httpBasic().disable().csrf().disable().cors().and(){...}` like this? i tried but still dont work

Comment: You need to allow the `Authorization` request header in your CORS config.